# How is possible to use resulted value from ReferenceField outside

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

```
const MyComponent = (props) => {
    //how I can use here user.fullName?
    //console.log(user.fullName)
    return (
        <ReferenceField
            reference="users"
            source="userId"
            record={props.record}
            link={false}
        >
            <UserNameField />
        </ReferenceField>
    );
};




const UserNameField = () => {
    return (
        <FunctionField<User>
            render={(user) => (user ? `${user.fullName ?? ''}` : '')}
        />
    );
};
```

how can I use `user.fullName` somewere outside of `ReferenceField`?

Answer (score 1):

The `ReferenceField` gets the `users` data by internally calling the app `datapProvider.getMany` method and making it available for its children.

If you want the same outside of it, you are going to have to ask for the data yourself